# TypeError: check() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, классы

Пытаюсь сделать условие на функцию из класса:

```py
if Static.check(delay=1, limit=3) == 0:
```

Но выдает ошибку:

```py
TypeError: check() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

В чем может быть проблема? Вот сам код класса:

```py
class Static:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__memory: list = []
        self.__ms: str = None

    def __while(self, delay: int):
        while True:
            self.__memory.append(delay)
            if len(self.__memory) == 30:
                break

        return self.__memory

    def __check(self, limit):
        if len(self.__memory) > limit:
            return 0
        return len(self.__memory)

    def __setup(self, delay: int, limit: int):
        self.__ms = f"{delay}|{limit}"

        for index in range(60):
            if self.__ms.isspace():
                break
            self.__ms = f"{limit}|{delay}"

    def __str_to_int_to_str(self):
        return map(round(str(int(str(self.__ms)))))

    def check(self, delay: int, limit: int):
        self.__while(delay)

        integer = self.__check(limit)

        self.__setup(integer, limit)

        self.__ms = self.__ms.split("|")[-1].strip()

        return self.__str_to_int_to_str()
```

Comment: Вы должны создать экземпляр класса и уже у него использовать данную функцию

Comment: А разве экземпляр класса уже не создан?

Comment: создание экземпляра класса выглядит так - `foo = Static()`
И у него уже используете функцию - `print(foo.check(delay=1, limit=3))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы использовать данную функцию, вы должны создать экземпляр класса:

```py
foo = Static()
if foo.check(delay=1, limit=3) == 0:
    ...
```